# SSJS Execute SQL and Retrieve Result

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, ssjs

Within SSJS, i want to execute SQL to retrieve a filtered data set from data extensions and views. Then i want to insert that data as a payload into a destination DE.

I got the second part working without an issue, to insert a payload into a DE. The part i am struggling with is to get the source data from the SQL select into a variable.

I cannot use SQL Query Activities since they do not support FLE.

Comment: The way you would "execute SQL" from SSJS is by calling an SQL Query Activity inside the system through the API. You mention that this is not possible in your usecase. I am not sure about the wording, but then it sounds like the requirement cannot really be met. You cannot write SQL statements directly in your SSJS code. What you can do is use retrieveRequests, e.g. via WSProxy, but not over multiple tables: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm

Comment: Are you wanting to decrypt your FLE data/filter on decrypted values?

Comment: @Macca Not looking to decrypt, just looking to get 100 rows from Data Extensions and Data Views and then insert the result set into a Data Extension which has FLE fields. So some values should be become encrypted.